# 403 Forbidden error in AJax call for Laravel API

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have two apis in Laravel.One is ouath token api and the other one is save api.

I am calling these two apis in a separate project folder which is in the same server. THe oauth token api is working fine. But the save api returns 403 forbidden error. The save api have XML data as request. I have already passed csrf token.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" />
        <title>AJAX PHP Post Request</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <style>
            body {
                color: #fff;
                background: #3598dc;
                font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            }
            .form-control {
                height: 41px;
                background: #f2f2f2;
                box-shadow: none !important;
                border: none;
            }
            .form-control:focus {
                background: #e2e2e2;
            }
            .form-control,
            .btn {
                border-radius: 3px;
            }
            .signup-form {
                width: 400px;
                margin: 30px auto;
            }
            .signup-form form {
                color: #999;
                border-radius: 3px;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
                background: #fff;
                box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                padding: 30px;
            }
            .signup-form h2 {
                color: #333;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-top: 0;
            }
            .signup-form hr {
                margin: 0 -30px 20px;
            }
            .signup-form .form-group {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            .signup-form input[type="checkbox"] {
                margin-top: 3px;
            }
            .signup-form .row div:first-child {
                padding-right: 10px;
            }
            .signup-form .row div:last-child {
                padding-left: 10px;
            }
            .signup-form .btn {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: bold;
                background: #3598dc;
                border: none;
                min-width: 140px;
            }
            .signup-form .btn:hover,
            .signup-form .btn:focus {
                background: #2389cd !important;
                outline: none;
            }
            .signup-form a {
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .signup-form a:hover {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .signup-form form a {
                color: #3598dc;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .signup-form form a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .signup-form .hint-text {
                padding-bottom: 15px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #responseContainer {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="signup-form">
            <form name="registrationForm" id="registrationForm" action="" method="post">
                <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='XFe2rTYl9WOpV8U6X5CfbIuOZOELJ97S' />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="registration"/>
                <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                <p>Please fill in this form to create an account!</p>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"  /></div>
                        <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"  /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password"  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" name="accept_terms"  /> I accept the <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> & <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
 
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="responseContainer">
                 
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="hint-text">Already have an account? <a href="#">Login here</a></div>
        </div>
    </body>
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
  function fromToXml(form){
    var xmldata=[];
    xmldata.push("<ECommerceAPI>");
    var inputs=form.elements;console.log(inputs);
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){        
      if (inputs[i].name){
        var el=document.createElement(inputs[i].name);
        el.textContent=inputs[i].value;
        xmldata.push(el.outerHTML);
      }
    }
    xmldata.push("</ECommerceAPI>");
    return xmldata.join("\n");
 }

            /*@ Registration start */
            $('#btnSubmit').click( function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
                }
            });  
                //let formData = $('#registrationForm').serialize();
                  var data=fromToXml(document.registrationForm);

                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'processRegistration.php',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
 
                        let res = JSON.parse(response);
 
                        $('#responseContainer').removeClass('alert-danger');
                        $('#responseContainer').addClass('alert-success');
                        $('#responseContainer').html(res.msg);
                        $('#responseContainer').show();
 
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
 
                        let res = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
 
                        $('#responseContainer').addClass('alert-danger');
                        $('#responseContainer').removeClass('alert-success');
                        $('#responseContainer').html(res.msg);
                        $('#responseContainer').show();
                    },
                });
            });
 
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**processRegistration.php**

```
   <?php 
 function XML2JSON($xml)
  {
    //echo $xml;
    if (!function_exists('normalizeSimpleXML')) {
      function normalizeSimpleXML($obj, &$result)
      {
        $data = $obj;
        if (is_object($data)) {
          $data = get_object_vars($data);
        }
        if (is_array($data)) {
          foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $res = null;
            normalizeSimpleXML($value, $res);
            if (($key == '@attributes') && ($key)) {
              $result = $res['value'];
            } else {
              $result[$key] = $res;
            }
          }
        } else {
          $result = $data;
        }
      }
      normalizeSimpleXML(simplexml_load_string($xml), $result);
      return json_encode($result);
    }
  }
  $xml = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $request = json_decode(XML2JSON($xml),true);
 

   /*@ Perform backend validation */
   $errors = '';
 
   $firstName = $request['first_name'];
   if ( empty($request['first_name']) ) {
      $errors .= '<li>First Name is required</li>';
   }
 
   $lastName = $request['last_name'];
   if ( empty($request['last_name']) ) {
      $errors .= '<li>Last Name is required</li>';
   }
 
   $email = $request['email'];
   if ( empty($request['email']) ) {
      $errors .= '<li>Email is required</li>';
   }
 
   if ( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
      $errors .= '<li>Invalid E-mail address</li>';
   }
 
   $password = $request['password'];
   if ( empty($request['password']) ) {
      $errors .= '<li>Password is required</li>';
   }
 
   $confirmPassword = $request['confirm_password'];
   if ( empty($request['confirm_password']) ) {
      $errors .= '<li>Confirm Password is required</li>';
   }
 
   if ( $password !== $confirmPassword ) {
      $errors .= '<li>Password & Confirm Password does not match</li>';  
   }
 
 
   if ( empty($errors) ) {
 
      /*@ Save your data in database and return respose */
      http_response_code( 200 );
      echo json_encode( [ 'msg' => 'Your registration has successfully done' ] );
 
   } else {
 
      /*@ Return errors */
 
      http_response_code( 406 ); 
      echo json_encode( [ 'msg' => $errors ] );
   }
```

But this same concept working in my another server. I have also having the same htaccess file in both servers.I also checked this api in postman and it worked fine. Is there any other configuration that I need to setup in my new server. Please help.

Thanks,
Rekha

I have added csrf token in ajax request. Also tried adding headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }

Also tried adding cross domain:true in my ajax rrquest.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is supposed to be returned by remote's and/or Web-Server's headers, sending it in request almost always does nothing.

Comment: Net communication has two sides (at least), and both need to work; In other words, provided intel is not enough to get a good answer, if any.

Comment: Are you using any FormRequest in the save function??? if yes check if its authorization is true..

Comment: Hi all,I have added the full code.Please help.

Comment: The code you've shared does not throw any 403 error. Also, it doesn't look like code related to Laravel. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is not Laravel code. This is simple php ajax sample code I tested in my both servers to verify working. In one server this code works fine. In another server, it is throwing 403 forbidden error.

Comment: The code you've shared does not contain any code that would throw such an error message. Share your attempts to resolve the problem, for example by removing code lines one by one to see which one triggers the problem

Comment: I can able to see the error in Inspect Element ->Fetch/XHR response.<html><head><title>Error 403 - Forbidden</title><head><body><h1>Error 403 - Forbidden</h1><p>You don't have permission to access the requested resource. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.</p></body></html>

Comment: Yeah, that's not a surprise. But you need to check where this error comes from. Does the server's error log contain any more details?

Comment: You're consuming an API, so you cab use Postman to send that same request to the Api and debug the problems. Of course don't forget to send the correct Authorization tokens when you're consuming that Api, it might help